# How can i loop through my String array and find the amount of occurrences of multiple strings?

Tags: java

I have an array in my modularized program and i am trying to find the amount of times Strings appear in the array. I cannot post my code as it violates my schools honor code, just looking some help....I cannot use any classes besides JOptionPane. Java code.

Comment: *I cannot post my code as it violates my schools honor code, just looking some help.* You should look at that honor code again.

Comment: Even you cannot post YOUR code, you can post similar code that does the same, a minimal and complete example, if you cannot it's that you do not understand what you're doing

Comment: You will need to post at least a very crude version of code. For example what kind of array do you have? `Object[]`? `String[]`?

Comment: do you just want to test if the value is any `String`? Or do you want to compare it against a certain `String`?

Comment: "I cannot use any classes besides JOptionPane"...  I think you may struggle with this.  At the very least, `String`, and some class with a `main` in it seems mandatory.

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure cause you dont post your code but i know you want that :

```
String[] yourArray = {"test", "1234","test"};
String yourStringTest = "test";
int occurence = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < yourArray.length;i++) {
    if(yourStringTest.equalsIgnoreCase(yourArray[i])) {
    occurence++;
    }
}
System.out.println("the string "+yourStringTest+" appear :"+occurence);
```

Comment: If it's work quote my answer to fine.(Use the check)